# Connection Timeout Expired: on SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to connect the database sever using SSMS locally.

But it is throwing the below error:

> Cannot connect to Server
>
> Connection Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed while attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement.  This could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was unable to respond back in time.  The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=4574; handshake=10433;  (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -2)
>
> The wait operation timed out

Server Info:

- SQL Server 2014 standard with SP1 on Windows Server 2008 R2 sp1.
- Windows firewall is not enabled.
- TCP/IP is also enabled.

This issue is showing up after the oracle client software was installed.
do we need to reboot the windows server ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did following steps and it worked for me

Restart WMI service:

- Start > Run > type services.msc and press Enter Scroll down to
  Windows Management Instrumentation, right click, restart

Restart the Windows server

Answer (score 0):

I was able to telnet SQL Server on SQL port (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/docast/2018/10/11/connection-timeout-and-command-timeout-in-sql-server/). So I have simply replaced the server name with its actual IP address and it worked for me. The same solution worked in the visual studio (Web.config - connection string) to access the DB in the application.